# Getting Error While Running React Native App

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build

I am facing the below error form yesterday when I am trying to run the project.

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDEVDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing

```
com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
     Dependency: androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0-alpha01.
     AAR metadata file: /Users/mac/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/fafe0388b6cc91ea7309174cddb01b56/browser-1.4.0-alpha01/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
```

Please help if anyone know this fix without update compileSdkVersion.

Answer (score 23):

I just fixed the issue with below code added to my `android/app/build.gradle` file inside android block:

```
android{ 

    // ....Existing codes

    configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
            }
        }
}
```

Hope it help others as form September 15, 2021 a new version released for `androidx.browser:1.4.0-alpha01` it contains minSDK version 31, it may causes the error.

Comment: Amazing, thanks Priyabrata. This solved the issue for me! How did you figure it out?

Comment: You can also use version 1.3.0 as that's more recent. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: For those who can't decide where to put it on the block: right in front of the curly braces that close the `android` block

Comment: Check this link for more details: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/browser

Answer (score 11):

I fixed it by adding this code to the `android/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies{
    ...other dependencies,

    implementation ("androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"){
        force = true
    }
}
```

This happens because there is an recent update to the [androidx.browser](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/browser#kts)
as of September 15, 2021 that require minSDK 31

Comment: This worked for us and fits better with the existing config, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add following config to android/app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
   // ... existing config
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify which version of androidx.browser you want to use in android/build.gradle like this:

```
buildscript {
  ext {
    ...other versions
    androidXBrowser = "1.3.0"
  }
}
```