# PendingIntent issue building React Native app for Android 12 (FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

Tags: android, react-native, android-pendingintent, android-12

Recently found out our app wasnt working for Android 12 users.

So I updated compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion to 31 and finally have it building..

Now when building it installs but crashes on start up. In logcat I found the following:

```
2021-10-30 17:17:56.596 17563-17587/com.walkabout.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-1
    Process: com.walkabout.app, PID: 17563
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.walkabout.app: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:273)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:151)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.forceStopRunnable(ForceStopRunnable.java:171)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:102)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

I found 2 dependencies that did use pendingIntent, so I updated to the latest versions but no luck, still the same error.

So I just removed those, then searched the entire project directory for pendingIntent, and none exist. Cleaned the project, npm install, npx react-native run-android. Still the same issue.

I'm not sure where to go from here, but I keep getting that error even though I cant find pendingIntent in any of my code or node_modules. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up targeting SDK 30 and added the following to build.gradle to use older version of some dependencies

[Android app won't build -- The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-beta01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037481/android-app-wont-build-the-mincompilesdk-31-specified-in-a-dependencys-an)

[Getting Error While Running React Native App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69208613/getting-error-while-running-react-native-app)

Comment: How did you find the two dependencies that used PendingIntent ?